# TimePicker:Silverlight Toolkit error: 'Invalid attribute value controls:LongListSelector for property TargetType'

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to implement the TimePicker in a new WP7 application..
But when i run the application...
There is always an  error  :

**'Invalid attribute value controls:LongListSelector for property TargetType'**

Here is my xaml Code

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="800"
    x:Class="WindowsPhoneApplication3.NewOrEditCoursePage"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" >

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="607"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="450" Margin="8,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="440">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" Margin="0,0,0,5" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}"/>
                    <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <controls:TimePicker Header="StartTime" Width="440" Height="100"/>
                <controls:TimePicker Header="EndTime" Width="440" Height="100" />
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Address" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}" />
                    <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="400" Margin="36,0,0,8" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" Height="80"/>
                <Button Content="Cancel" Width="200" Height="80"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

By the way , i have added the "Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll"

Answer (score 0):

You posted the wrong XAML. We need the XAML for the Control.

Anyway, the error message means that you attempted to set a `Value` property on the `LongListSelector`. The `LongListSelector` control don't expose such a dependency property, and thus you can't set it.